# android animation of button

Tags: android, animation, button, coordinates

In my app there are 8 buttons animating from the top of the screen to the bottom. During its journey, I would like to check its x and y coordinates, simply by using a timer, where when the milliseconds is, for example, `%3000 =0`, it will invoke the following method to update the coordinates of all the buttons:

### Checking method:

```
   public void Check_all_Spot(int BOY_X)
   {  
       apple_shown_length = Math.min(spot_count,INITIAL_SPOTS); 

       if (apple_shown_length >0)
       {
           for (int w = 0; w < apple_shown_length ; ++w)
           {
               spots[w].setText("x="+ spots[w].getX() +"\ny="+ spots[w].getY());       
           }
       }
   }
```

### Timer:

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        //updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (timeInMilliseconds / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (timeInMilliseconds % 1000);

        String milliscond_shown = String.format("%03d", milliseconds).substring(0,1);
        tv_timing.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":" + milliscond_shown);
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);

        check_indicator = Integer.parseInt(milliscond_shown); 
        if (check_indicator %3 ==0 && quit ==false)
        {
            Check_all_Spot(boy_x);
        }

                );
    }
};
```

## Question:

Without the above method, the timer runs smoothly, and the 8 buttons work perfectly for its journey, from top to bottom (if one button vanishes, another new one will be created from the top and start animation).

Yet, when adding this method, the first button is created and shown, but then everything on the screen and also the timer freezed.

The logcat does not show any red messages. I can `OnPause` switching to other application freely.

Comment: remove that Thread stuff and create a class that extends TranslateAnimation and overrides applyTransformation method

Comment: applyTransformation's first parameter is in range <0..1> and changes during the animation